# Is it possible to pull an image URL from Google Images to Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am building a simple web app for a teacher at my school that includes a word, a translation, and an image. The data will be used to generate the web app layout.

[image]

Col B already uses a formula `=GOOGLETRANSLATE(A2,"en","ko")` to generate the translation. Is it possible to do something like this to get the URL for an image based on a word? For example, get the URL for an image of "bread" in cell C2. This means all the teacher will need to do is add the English word and the translation and image will be added automatically.

I tried things like `=("https://www.google.com/search?q="&A2&"&tbm=isch")` in C2, but this gives me a search page. Is there either:

A way to pull the first image off Google Images?

OR

Another site that provides images based on a simplified URL? For example, a site where I could enter "www.madeupsite.com/bread" and get an image of bread?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this function exists as of now. I think a good idea if you are trying the alternative is to make an HTML repl on REPL.IT - there you can upload images and the file path will be made for you. For example: https://replname.replusername.repl.co/folder/word.jpg

Hope this helps

Comment: Here is what it looks like! https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vqbdDrNve39Ve-4flV7CZgk3M9zOHdoJMKiSgct4LQU/edit?usp=sharing